# Can / Should `signalAll` be within the `finally` block?

Tags: java, thread-safety, locking, conditional-statements, try-catch-finally

When using a `Lock` with a `Condition`, e.g.,

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
```

and locking, i.e.,

`lock.lock();`

then while it is not ok to continue, e.g.,

```
try {
  while (!ok_to_continue) {
```

we `await` the `condition`:

```
    condition.await();
  }
```

Then, *typically*, after we're done with our *thread unsafe business*, any or all `await`ing threads are signalled using `signal` or `signalAll` in the `try` block, i.e.,

```
condition.signalAll();
```

before ensuring the lock is unlocked, i.e.:

```
} finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

By *typically* I mean: as recommended by programming teachers, Java books<sup>[[1](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Core_Java_Volume_I_Fundamentals.html?id=MdxACwAAQBAJ)]</sup> and Oracle<sup>[[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal--)]</sup> the `signal` and `signalAll` method are called in the `try` block. As per Oracle's documentation, these methods are typically called while the corresponding `Lock` is held by the current thread. Does this mean the `signal` and `signalAll` methods can also be called in the `finally` block instead of before? Why is it *typical* to signal `await`ing threads from within the `try` block, where an exception may be thrown by the *thread unsafe business*? In other words, we can't be sure the `signal` or `signalAll` methods are called at all, am I correct? Why then is it not typical to ensure they *are* called by calling them in the `finally` block? That is:

```
} finally {
  condition.signalAll();
  lock.unlock();
}
```

By calling one of them in the `finally` block, we ensure an `await`ing thread is activated and a deadlock could be prevented.

What are uses of either construct and why would Oracle use the condition in the `try` block instead of in the `finally` block?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to signal if we don't know that the precondition has been met (in your example `ok_to_continue`). Conversely, it doesn't make sense to hold a lock if we're not executing code that relies on it. In both cases we don't really know the state, but I think the default assumption is different.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The `ok_to_continue` expression may indeed throw an exception, thus making the condition uncertain. However, while the *thread unsafe business* we were about to execute now isn't going to be executed anymore, in some cases we might want to ensure another thread `await`ing the condition will be `signal`led, hence my question remains. Besides, we could add a `catch` clausule for the `ok_to_continue` expression (as well as for the *thread unsafe business*). Is that the recommended approach, catching exceptions if you expect `signal` or `signalAll` may not be called?